# Unable to authenticate proxy when starting SQL snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sql, merge-replication

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 install running SQL Server 2008 R2 with all the latest updates etc applied,

I have restored a database from an old image (SQL 2005) and am trying to get web-sync working with merge subscriptions.

However when I attempt to start the SQL Snapshot Agent on the distribution I have defined I get this error:

`Unable to start execution of step 2 (reason: Error authenticating proxy SERVER-NAME\Administrator, system error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.).  The step failed.`

I am starting the agent as the computer admin and am not using a proxy server.

Any ideas on why this might show up?

See below:

[image]

```
The params used by the SQL Snapshot agent are:

-Publication

-Publisher

-Distributor

-PublisherDB

-ReplicationType

If you are using SQL Server Authentication (I am), you must also specify the following arguments:

-DistributorLogin

-DistributorPassword

-DistributorSecurityMode = 0

-PublisherLogin

-PublisherPassword

-PublisherSecurityMode = 0
```

Comment: Can you post the parameters from step 2 of the job?  Be sure to mask any passwords.

Comment: Hi @mrdenny, I have attached a screenshot above, All I am doing is right clicking the publication, clicking view snapshot agent status and clicking start and I am confronted with that.

Comment: Can you edit the SQL Agent job which is what actually runs the Replication agent and show those properties?

Comment: Hi @mrdenny, see above, I have added what params are needed by the snapshot agent, I can find the procedure too if needed?

Comment: Are those the only parameters which are specified in the SQL Agent job?

Comment: According to MSDN yes that's it...

Comment: I know what's posted on MSDN and the help docs.  What's on your actual server in the SQL Agent job?

Comment: @mrdenny, It should be just that (It is a fresh build and I don't know how to access the job - do you know the sp-name?)

Comment: In object explorer connect to the distributor and, navigate to "SQL Server Agent" > Jobs and find the job that is named {ServerName}-{PublishedDatabaseName}-{PublicationName} and edit that job.  You'll want to look at step 2.

Comment: No problem, if you can't find it let me know and we'll work through it.